# React drop down doesn't open option in an fixed div

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, css-position, dropdown

These are the imports I used to create my dropdown

```
 import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
 import Autocomplete from '@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete';
```

css

```
.fixed{position: fixed;}
```

Data

```
const  options = [ "Baseball", "Basketball", "Cricket", "Field Hockey", "Football", "Table 
 Tennis", "Tennis", "Volleyball" ];
```

If I don't use fixed div, the dropdown opens of all the options properly. But I need this fixed class. Neither I can  understand the issue  nor I can find any solution

```
 return (
  <div className="fixed">
  <Autocomplete
  options={options}
  style={{ width: 300 }}
  renderInput={(params) =>
    <TextField {...params} label="Combo box" variant="outlined"  />}
/>
</div>
)
```

Comment: When position is fixed try to give some more width and hight and check. It could be hiding in background

Comment: Am I supposed to add heigh and width of drop down? Tried.Not working @Mahesh

Comment: Set some Width and hight for fixed position div and inspect it and see. How it is rendering in background